# What could cause water hammer after changing a valve cartridge?

Tags: bathroom, shower, faucet, water-pressure

I fixed my delta 1400 series shower faucet the other day by replacing the valve cartridge with a non-delta brand.

Everything went well, until I turned it on, now the shower pipe is hammering.  The tub pipe is fine, no hammering at all.

Any ideal as to why this would happen?  I replace the one in the master bath and had no issues at all (I think I used delta brand for that one).

My understanding is that the cause of the hammering is an increase in water pressure in the pipe.  The only thing that changed was the new cartridge.  Could the after market one be the cause?

Comment: Does it bang once when you turn the water on, once when you turn the water off, or constantly (bang, bang, bang) the whole time the water is on?

Comment: The volume of the bang is depended on the position of the handle, far end of the hot no banging, move towards cold water the banging starts and will continue until - with varying degree of noise until close to cold water then it stops

Comment: I had the same problem when I replaced the cartridge. The hammering occurs when someone opens and closes another faucet in the bathroom. It also occurs when you turn it near mid range (equal hot and cold). I'd hate to have to install pressure relieving devices on both lines near the shower.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I found.  I went to the hardware store and located two of the replacement valve cartridge made by Delta.  Reading the back of them I found that one was for faucet made after 2005 and the other was for faucet made before 2006.  Being that my house was built in 2000 I went for the one made before 2006.  I then replaced the after market cartridge with the new one from Delta and now life is good.

The after market product does not mention anything about manufacturing year so I am thinking it is for newer versions of the Delta 1400 Series shower faucets.

Comment: Thanks for the self answer. Continuous banging does indicate the issue is likely in the valve. If it was a single bang, I would have suspected you knocked a bracket loose in the process of replacing the valve.

Comment: and thank you for this post. We had the same issue - after replacig the valve in the shower, there was a banging on the pipes behind the wall when turn another faucet in the house on and off. We tried draining the water and getting the air out, and we were ready to call a plumber, already thinking how we will have to remove the wall. After I read this post we bought another shower cartrige, made before 2006, and voilla - problem fixed - no more banging on the pipes. Thank you and God Bless you for taking the time to post your experience.
Rossi

Answer (score 1):

I changed out my shower faucet cartridge about 6 months ago and shortly afterwards the pipes starting banging all through the house.

We had a plumber over and we spent half the day tracking down which pipe was causing all the noise but couldn't find any pipes that were loose.

We changed out the cartridge and magically the banging stopped. It turns out the cartridge was leaking by allowing cold water to leak into the hot water side which would cause my tankless water heater to turn on briefly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Knocking coming from my master bathroom sink and when I flushed the toilet along with the shower. After checking out a couple of blogs I decided to replace my shower cartridge. I had a delco universal one in there. After installing the Delta cartridge made before 2006 the knocking went away.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Danco cartridge for Delta 1300/1400 series faucets.
I installed it and the water flowed fine but pipes started banging.
It was the correct cartridge.
I then found a Delta brand cartridge and installed it and, voila, the banging stopped.  It seems the Danco cartridge fits too tightly.  It was quite difficult taking it out.  Maybe that creates some type of vacuum that is not needed.  I don't know; just save yourself some time and get the Delta cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with the Danco cartridge.
Store I bought the Danco cartridge did not carry the Delta cartridge, but the other store that is Orange did.  As soon as I put the Delta cartridge in, the problem was solved, and the cartridge slid right in unlike the Danco.

Answer (score 0):

The Delta Cartridge most likely has its own mini arrestor's built into the unit. This would be the reason for the difference.

They have an Anti-scald device so this would regulate the temperature as pressure changes (for example a toilet flush) - what this does is regulate the pressure of the hot side in relation to the cold side.

Your DANCO or other non-oem cartridges may not have this feature.

The old adage you get what you pay for is very relevant in this case.